# Seeing Extent report from previous builds rather than the current build

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, automation, extentreports

I am facing an issue in which I am getting the OLD Extent Report.

Here is the Configurations:

[image]

Once I have executed the build from Jenkins and when the build completes - HTML Reports get generated.

[image]

Here is the pom.xml file configuration
[image]

Here is the TestNG.xml file configuration

[image]

[image]
Also on the console, I get the following message :

[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...

[htmlpublisher] Archiving at PROJECT level D:\BITS2_GIT\BITSAutomation\test-output to C:\Users\aakash.paliwal.jenkins\jobs\Bits Local Project\htmlreports\Bug_20Report

Comment: Are you seeing report from previous builds rather than the current build?

Comment: @Sureshmani Yes

Comment: Make sure current jobs are not throwing exceptions. I have a similar issue, when I run a job to run with Chrome and new Edge. After the suite finishes running on Chrome, it throws exception when running with Edge. Cucumber reports generate fine, but Extent Report does not. To make sure this is not the case, examine the console output for the builds not showing up.